# Amplify "Incorrect username or password"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm building an app on iOS and Android (both native language) and I'm using AWS Amplify for the auth part. Everything was working fine until I decided to recreate from scratch all my AWS instances on a different server region using Terraform and changing my `awsconfiguration.json` file accordingly.

Now I can successfully create new users account from my app but I cannot log in, I always got this response: `notAuthorized(message: "Incorrect username or password.")`

All my users are `CONFIRMED` in Cognito and they can successfully change their password from the client app but impossible to login, on iOS and on Android.

I also tried to delete all the amplify files from my project, creating a new Amplify project with the CLI  `amplify init` and then generating all the nw files for my new instances with `amplify add --apiId #####`

After some research It seems that this problem can be related to a race condition like is saying @palpatim on the repo [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1575)

But I tried to reconnect my app to my first Cognito instance and it's still working fine so I don't think that it's SDK related.

I have no idea of what can help you to point me on the right direction so if you have any question I'll edit my question with the details asked.

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @ZubairZahoor I deleted everything and started over to get it working